# how to get all possible query for a same goal?

Tags: sql, algorithm

I wanna ask about sql. Is there possible to get all variance in sql that the goal is same?

May be use application, plugin or etc,,

Thank you

This is the example.

---

GOAL: “Cities with at least two suppliers”

---

Self-Join approach

```
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM Tb_Supplier S1, Tb_Supplier S2 
WHERE S1.City=S2.City AND S1.Supp_ID<>S2.Supp_ID
```

Sub-Query approach

```
SELECT S.City
FROM Tb_Supplier S
WHERE S.City IN  
    (SELECT City
     FROM Tb_Supplier
     WHERE Supp_ID<>S.Supp_ID)
```

Group By approach

```
SELECT City 
FROM Tb_Supplier
GROUP BY City HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Im sorry about that, Im not good enough in english,,
=D
just like this, 
Can we get all possible sql that the goal is same but the query statement is different ?
suppose, I want to make many answer key in sql question bank, because there are many students who answer with different way, 
can I get these sql keys instantly..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the sup_id is the PK, then you want to do the group by:

```
SELECT t.City
FROM 
(SELECT City, COUNT(sup_id) as [totalSuppliers]
    FROM tb_supplier
    GROUP BY City 
    HAVING COUNT(sup_id) > 1) as t
```

Comment: thank you so much for ur answer, :)
seems like my question is unreadable,, hoho

Comment: actually I want to make many answer key in sql question bank, because there are many students who answer with different way, can I get these sql keys instantly..?

Comment: Not sure what you are wanting in your comments.  Your original post had no mention of students.  If you are wanting every possible combination, then use a cross join.  If you want a key, then use a guid (newid()) function.

Comment: O i see, :)
so you know that there are 3 approaches in my example and all of them give a same table result, all of these can answer the goal question "get the Cities with at least two suppliers". Here, I want to know how can I get all of the sql statement (above are 3 approach) that can give me for a goal? may be using  plug in, programs, or etc.